# ERROR. Spring MVC 4 + JSon + Jquery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, json, spring-mvc, autocomplete, controller

I want use Jquery autocomplete control with json.
I have the next **error** message: **Could not find acceptable representation**

I imported **maven dependencies**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

I have in my distpatcher-servlet.xml next line too:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
```

my **controller**:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user/json/search", produces="application/json")
    public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> findFriends(@RequestParam("term") String text) {
        Map<String, Object> mapFriends = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        List<User> lstFriends = userService.findByNameOrAliasContaining(text);

        for (int i = 0; i < lstFriends.size(); i++) {
            User user = lstFriends.get(i);
            mapFriends.put("friend" + i, user.getAlias() + " " + user.getAlias());

        }

        return mapFriends;
    }
```

my view.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Insert title here</title>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <!-- Load jQuery UI CSS  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<!-- Load jQuery JS -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
<!-- Load jQuery UI Main JS  -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>


    <script>
        $(function() {      
            $("#txtSearchFriends").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.getJSON("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/user/json/search", {
                        term: request.term
                    }, response);
                }
            });
        });
  </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        Enter Name: <input id="txtSearchFriends"> 
    </body>
</html>
```

my question: **WHY DOESNT WORK??**

if necessary the **trace** is this:
`org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:251) org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:153) org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:165) org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:80) org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:126) org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814) org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737) org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969) org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624) org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316) org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122) org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:149) org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48) org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205) org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120) org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53) org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91) org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213) org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169) org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423) org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079) org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625) org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem and the solution.

There is a issus with JSON 1.X + Spring 4.1+
You need **change jackson dependencies** for use Jackson 2.3+ for this others:

**com.fasterxml.jackson.core**

- jackson-core
- jackson-databind